# JSTree - Add action to Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jstree

I am having a little problem with JSTree (https://www.jstree.com/).

To simplify, i have an tree of projects, and i want to put an action before the name of each listed projects (an action to go to project using fontawesome), i already know how to make an redirect using JS, but JSTree do not allow me to insert this action on my tree.

In a visual way i need to do something like:

- (ICON-ARROW-ACTION) NAME
- (ICON-ARROW-ACTION) NAME 2

  - (ICON-ARROW-ACTION) NAME 3

I am doing something like this:

(HTML)

```
<div id="jstree_projects">
  <ul>
    <li data-jstree='{"opened":true}'>
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-fw redirect_project"
         data-url="<?= site_url('ON CLICK THIS ACTION, REDIRECT TO THIS URL'); ?>">
      </i>
      PROJECT NAME
      <ul>
        <li data-jstree='{"opened":true}'>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-fw redirect_project"
             data-url="<?= site_url('ON CLICK THIS ACTION, REDIRECT TO THIS URL'); ?>">
          </i>
          PROJECT NAME 2
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(CSS)

```
#jstree_projects{
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.redirect_project{
  color: yellow;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

(JS)

```
$('#jstree_projects').jstree();
```

If anyone may help me, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [select_node.jstree](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=select_node.jstree) event. It will provide you the selected `node` object and the related data to it. Also, you can check is it the last item in the list with the property `children: []`.

I have created a jsFiddle for you, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xristo91/ndp200mk/).
The only change that I did was to move the `data-url` attribute to the `<li>` tag.